# Como passar um xml para o foreach sem o uso de arquivo?

Tags: php, xml

À partir dos dados retornados por uma query, gostaria de gerar um xml, mas sem salvá-lo em arquivo e percorrer as tags do xml para tratar os dados de alguma forma.
Gostaria de saber como passar o xml para o foreach sem ter esse xml em arquivo.

Suponhamos que o xml gerado seja:

```
<disciplinas>
<disciplina id="1">
    <periodo>1</periodo>
    <nome>matematica</nome>
</disciplina>
<disciplina id="id_disciplina">
    <periodo>1</periodo>
    <nome>portugues</nome>
</disciplina>
<disciplina id="2">
    <periodo>1</periodo>
    <nome></nome>
</disciplina>
<disciplina id="3">
    <periodo>2</periodo>
    <nome>historia</nome>
</disciplina>
</disciplinas>
```

Com o xml, eu quero verificar os dados para gerar uma tabela com rowspan onde os valores do "periodo" se repetem

[image: tabela com rowspan]

ao invés de uma tabela sem rowspan.

[image: tabela sem rowspan]

Comment: você quer fazer print to xml no ecrã sem gerar download de ficheiro?

Comment: Mas qual o objetivo disso? Se você não vai armazenar em arquivo, no mínimo você vai ecoar o resultado para, quem sabe, ser usado com AJAX. Porém, sendo isso mesmo, pra quê você quer criar o XML, percorrê-lo e alterar algum valor e então, talvez, exibi-lo, se você pode fazer o oposto, iterando o array retornado da query, tratar o que precisa e só então montar o XML já pronto?

Comment: @Luís Henrique, você alterou a pergunta, mas minha resposta ainda serve para seu caso. Entretanto, já estou me questionando se você quer na verdade, transformar este XML em um array ou objeto para poder fazer o foreach. É isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Simples:

1. `query`
2. processa com o `laço`;
3. gera `string` XML
4. `echo`  no `header` e no `XML` como body do documento

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$test_array = array (
  'bla' => 'blub',
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'another_array' => array (
    'stack' => 'overflow',
  ),
);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Resultado:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <blub>bla</blub>
  <bar>foo</bar>
  <overflow>stack</overflow>
</root>
```

Considere `$test_array` como o resultado do processamento no passo 2